# prevent creation of object with static lifetime

Tags: c++, static, heap-memory, stack-memory

Can we prevent creation of objects with static lifetime, while at the same time allowing objects to be created with automatic lifetime?

If we want to prevent users from creating instances of a class with automatic duration, we can make the destructor private. and if we want to prevent users from creating instances with dynamic allocation, we can make `operator new` private.

I think it is impossible to prevent users from creating objects with static storage duration, because the only difference is the lifetime. but perhaps some experts here can devise a way.

Comment: Why, why, WHY on Earth would you do want to do that. It's a complete waste of time and effort.

Comment: @VJo "can we restrict the object creation only on static storage area, while at the same time allowing objects to be created on stack."

Comment: @cat++ I was also thinking why someone would like to restrict on stack & on heap. but i have seen people specify the dynamic memory for some particular process.  similarly I thought may be someone would like to specify static memory also.

Comment: @Amar: Those are stupid as well, just don't, there is no sane use case for this. It's an utter design failure, like a singleton, only worse.

Comment: A singleton is not in and of itself a design failure. ;p

Comment: @Amar, this is a very unusual request. Please explain it a little more so that we can see the reasoning behind it, maybe there's a different answer to your problem.

Comment: @mark I don't have any reasoning behind the question. It's just came to my mind that lets try to restrict the users from creating object with static lifetime. request you to find the possible rational behind any such request. I mean where we can use such restriction.

Comment: This seems like a very useful question.  The invocation of the destructor on an object that is allocated in static storage is [quite complex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) and might involve dependencies on other objects that are already destroyed.  One may want to safeguard against this.

Answer (score 2):

There is **no language** facility which helps at compile time. But at runtime you can use below technique to **restrict that**. Suppose you don't want `MyObject` on `static` storage area, then add the code in destructor as:

```
bool ALLOW_OBJECTS = false;  // global variable
struct MyObject  // class body
{
 ~MyObject ()
  {
    if(ALLOW_OBJECTS == false)
      <print error message>
    // ...
  }
};
```

Now, in your `main()` method you can have `ALLOW_OBJECTS` as,

```
int main ()
{
  ALLOW_OBJECTS = true;  // objects can be created now
// ... other code
  ALLOW_OBJECTS  = false;  // reset to 'false' before main() ends
}
```

Now it's a fact that variables declared in `static` storage vanish their lifetime (call destructor) after `main()` finishes. Thus, if a variable was declared on `static` storage, its destructor will print an error message (in file or stdout).

With this check your 1 execution test run may fail, but you can manually correct the code after you find the number of error messages. So in your production code you can remove all those debug statements and you will have your code **without any** `static` **storage object** !!! (not applicable for PODs and pointers).

Comment: This does not cover `static` variables defined inside functions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a receipt on wikibooks [Requiring or Prohibiting Heap-based Objects](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Requiring_or_Prohibiting_Heap-based_Objects).

The point is to make a class destructor to be protected so the using statically created object will generate a compile-time error. The drawback is that you have to implement and invoke a separate **delete** method for your class.

```
class HeapOnly {
  public:
    HeapOnly() {} 
    void destroy() const { delete this; }
  protected:
    ~HeapOnly() {}
};
HeapOnly h1;     // Destructor is protected so h1 can't be created globally
HeapOnly func()  // Compiler error because destructor of temporary is protected
{
  HeapOnly *hoptr = new HeapOnly; // This is ok. No destructor is invoked automatically for heap-based objects
  return *hoptr;
}
int main(void) {
  HeapOnly h2; // Destructor is protected so h2 can't be created on stack
}
```